# get only string after matching pattern and exclude everything else

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I would like to get string which comes after matching pattern and exclude everything else. For example say,

```
Nov 17 21:52:06 web01-san roundcube: <he1v330n> User dxxssjksdfd [121.177.26.200]; \
Message for undisclosed-recipients:, stanpiatt@yahoo.com
Nov 17 21:48:26 web01-san roundcube: <fqu8k29l> User cxcnjdfdssd [121.177.26.200]; \
Message for undisclosed-recipients:, stanpiatt@yahoo.com
```

So I would like to get **ONLY** string after pattern `User` and exclude everything else, so output should be

```
User dxxssjksdfd
User cxcnjdfdssd
```

I've tried `grep -Po 'User\K[^\s]*'` but it doesn't give what I want. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Solution 1st:***
Following `awk` should be helping you in same.

```
awk -v RS=" " '/User/{getline;print "User",$0}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
User dxxssjksdfd
User cxcnjdfdssd
```

***Solution 2nd:*** You could use following too by going through the fields of line too.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /User/){print $i,$(i+1)}}}'   Input_file
```

***Solution 3rd:*** By using `sub` utility of `awk` here too.

```
awk 'sub(/.*User/,""){print "User",$1}'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ cat infile
Nov 17 21:52:06 web01-san roundcube: <he1v330n> User dxxssjksdfd [121.177.26.200]; \
Message for undisclosed-recipients:, stanpiatt@yahoo.com
Nov 17 21:48:26 web01-san roundcube: <fqu8k29l> User cxcnjdfdssd [121.177.26.200]; \
Message for undisclosed-recipients:, stanpiatt@yahoo.com
```

Using `grep`

```
$ grep -Po 'User [^\s]*'  infile
User dxxssjksdfd 
User cxcnjdfdssd
```

Using `awk`

```
$ awk  'match($0,/User [^ ]*/){ print substr($0, RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  infile
User dxxssjksdfd
User cxcnjdfdssd
```

Using **GNU** `awk`

```
$ awk  'match($0,/User [^ ]*/,arr){ print arr[0]}'  infile
User dxxssjksdfd
User cxcnjdfdssd
```

**Explanation:**

`/User [^\s]*/`

- `User` matches the characters User literally (case sensitive)
- Match a single character not present in the list below `[^\s]*`
- `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

Comment: amazing and nice explanation.